# NSFileHandle and removing a section of bytes

Tags: cocoa, nsfilehandle

I'm a bit surprised because I believe that there is no obvious way to delete a section of bytes of a file.

That is, suppose I have a file that holds 900 GB, and want to delete 8 bytes starting from offset 54.

Is there any way to do it without passing data to memory?

Thank you!

Comment: **SOLVED:**

My question had a big conceptual error: filesystems do not support adding or deleting data in the middle sections of a file.